# How to set correct position of nodes in gojs timeline?

Tags: gojs

i am new to gojs

I am working on gojs timeline sample which is by default functionality based on dates. but i have changed dates to numbers.with the below range like

0,20,40,60.....380.but my problem is the nodes are not pointing to exact positions 
in the line bar.

I think there is a problem with convertDateToX(d) function.can any one help me

Comment: That sample definitely assumes that all of the values are instances of Date.  You'll need to change all of the code that works with Dates and replace it with code that works with numbers.

Comment: my apologise! its working fine now when i comment sorting code..